# Subclassing custom CollectionView Cell doesn't show parent UI

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a custom cell that i create from xib.

It looks like this:

[image: collectionViewCell]

And i have 2 other cells created only in class that subclass it.

And need to add different views to the `containerView`

So in my `UIViewController` i register all cells.

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
    didSet {
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.register(cell1.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
        collectionView.register(cell2.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "ParentCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "parentCell")
    }
}
```

and dequeueing the cells.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! cell1
        cell.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        return cell
    }

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! cell2
    cell.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    return cell
}
```

but the app crashes with

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

when i try to use `containerView`

Any suggestions how to implement this?
Thanks

---

EDIT:

My problem is that the views from the parent cell are not getting instantiated. 
I understand what

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

means. i dont understand why are the view not getting instantiated.

The crash is on

```
cell.containerView.backgroundColor
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: @Mr.Bista please read my question again, its not the same.

Comment: I know, but error is self explanatory, also can you point out on exactly which line the error occurs?

Comment: See my edit... this doesn't help... thanks anyway

Comment: "i dont understand why are the view not getting instantiated." , you might have put wrong cell identifier name.

Comment: no, the right cell is getting instantiated, the parent views from the xib are not.